# Can't compile runnable that calls itself?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, runnable

I'm trying to make a `Runnable` that calls itself:

```
class A {
  public void f() {
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // do stuff, return if it worked.
        r.run(); // otherwise try again
      }
    };
  }
}
```

It gets this error:

```
$ javac A.java
A.java:6: error: variable r might not have been initialized
        r.run(); // otherwise try again
        ^
1 error
```

Why? Is there something special in the standard library definition of `Runnable` which removes the guarantee that the interface implementation is fully defined before it is used (perhaps for example, it has some code that gets run whenever you make an implementation of it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Runnable. Rather, this compiler error results because the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment happens *before* the assignment.

In this case, the compiler doesn't have a trivial way of knowing if `r` is [definitely assigned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) if/when the variable expression is *actually* executed and thus forbids the access entirely.

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) *must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs.*

Consider the following which illustrates the issue and fails with the same compiler error as the originally posted example.

```
final String r = (new Object() {
    public String toString() {
        // -> error: variable r might not have been initialized
        // (And in this case it is indeed *not* assigned!)
        return "Hello " + r + "!";
    }
}).toString();
```

---

Reply to Dog's comment:

> .. This was my thought exactly, when I came across the error today. But I can't think of any reason why it doesn't just assume r is defined by the time the interface implementation is defined.

In the above example a case is shown where the variable `r` is *definitely* accessed before it is assigned. Likewise, if the constructor called a virtual method (say `run`) then it *could* be accessed before it is assigned - but this case can't be detected across a compilation unit.

This is further problematic with `final` and access in the anonymous type: Java does *not* create a closure over the final variables, but rather *binds the values* of those variables when it creates an instance of the anonymous type. This creates an invalid cyclic relation between access to the variable (which is really access to the previously bound value) and the creation of the anonymous instance.

Comment: What's wrong with your code example? It looks like it should work to me.

Comment: @Dog It won't compile and will result in `error: variable r might not have been initialized`.

Comment: When you say "happens before", are you talking about the formal relationship `happens-before` used in shared memory contexts?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't compile, but I don't understand why.

Comment: No. There is no concurrency issue here. The [definite assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) of `v` only occurs *after* the assignment statement. The error results because of this.

Comment: If your `Runnable` class is so complex that it creates another `Runnable` inside, you could consider making it a named class, instead of an anonymous one.  It could still be an inner class, if it needs to refer to members of the top level class.  But giving it a name will make it possible for the inner `Runnable` to refer to the first runnable by name.

Comment: "In this case, the compiler doesn't have a trivial way of knowing if r is definitely assigned if/when the variable expression is actually executed and thus forbids the access entirely." This was my thought exactly, when I came across the error today. But I can't think of any reason why it doesn't just assume `r` is defined by the time the interface implementation is defined.

Comment: Oh, I misread your example, didn't notice it was assigning `r` the result of calling `toString`, instead of the object.

Answer (score 3):

> Can't compile runnable that calls itself?

You can -- just don't qualify the `run()` method's name with `r`; you can unambiguously refer to a method within itself:

```
class A {
  public void f() {
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        ...
        run();  // notice that there is no `r.`
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The problem in your code is that you're trying to use the variable `r` before it's fully initialized. It's kind of like:

```
int x = x;
```

which of course is invalid (and produces the same error message).

Comment: That workaround sort of helps, but I still get the same error if I make an inner `Runnable` inside `r` that calls `r.run()`.

Comment: @Dog You can't call the outer `run()` from within another `Runnable` -- the inner `Runnable` knows nothing about where it's being declared. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you. How does that explain why the code doesn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

You could save this pointer and call Run method in a new Runnable :

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // if condition met and need to run more
            final Runnable that = this;
            executor.execute(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { that.run(); } });
        }
    };
```